# How to set a User Profile Date field programmatically to a null value via CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, user-profile-property, pnp

I am trying to remove a value of a user profile date field.  We have a date field, SPS-HireDate, that I would like to clear in certain circumstances.

I am using PowerShell, specifically `Set-PnPUserProfileProperty`.

The `Set-PnPUserProfileProperty` is really just calling `PeopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(AccountName, PropertyName, Value);` behind the scenes.

```
Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $UserUPN -Property 'SPS-HireDate' -Value $EmptyDate
```

I have tried

```
$EmptyDate = ""
$EmptyDate = $null
$EmptyDate = [DateTime]::MinValue
[Nullable[DateTime]]$EmptyDate = $null
```

How can I remove the value from a User Profile Property Date field using C# or PowerShell CSOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"

$SiteURL="https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com"
$UserName="dennis@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "xxx"
$AccountName="dennis@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)

#Bind to Site Collection
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = $Creds

$PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($ctx)
$PeopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty("i:0#.f|membership|"+$AccountName,"SPS-HireDate", "")
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try SetSingleValueProfileProperty by itself and see if it works.    I won't be able to get to it until tomorrow though.

Comment: Any update? Did you solve this issue?